# PreparedStatement setBinaryStream in JPA

Tags: jpa, prepared-statement, bytearrayinputstream

in JDBC I use this:

```
PreparedStatement pupd;

pupd.setBinaryStream(5, new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, ofs, lgt), lgt);
```

How can I accomplish the same result using JPA?
This is a real time application so converting to some byte[] stored in memory is out of question.
Also, I'm writing neutral code, meaning I'm not using any specific JPA implementation.

thanks in advance,
ML

Comment: JPA does not support streaming

Comment: Really? is there some workaround to stream the data using JPA?